# Can’t setup yb-master with TLS encryption in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I am trying to setup yb-master nodes with TLS encryption. I followed the doc and applied the configurations accordingly. I am receiving the following error:

```
W0113 18:45:22.847903 28992 universe_key_client.cc:60] Rpc status: Network error (yb/rpc/secure_stream.cc:562): Handshake failed: Network error (yb/rpc/secure_stream.cc:882): Endpoint does not match, address: ip2, hostname: ip2, resp:
W0113 18:45:22.851953 28981 tcp_stream.cc:144] { local: ip1:7100 remote: ip3:59128 }: Shutting down with pending inbound data ({ capacity: 374400 pos: 0 size: 67 }, status = Network error (yb/rpc/secure_stream.cc:472): Insecure connection header: 5942)
W0113 18:45:22.852005 28981 tcp_stream.cc:144] { local: ip1:7100 remote: ip3:59128 }: Shutting down with pending inbound data ({ capacity: 374400 pos: 0 size: 67 }, status = Service unavailable (yb/rpc/reactor.cc:100): Shutdown connection (system error 108))
```

From what I see, the endpoints actually match. Anyone has idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have that ip address in your cert? Do you connect over that ip? You need to have the ip address in the cert. It should work after updating the certs.